# Generating K-space from magnitude and phase

Tags: matlab, fft, complex-numbers, ifft, phase

My question might be simple but I really need to make sure that the process I am doing is valid.

The MRI scanner acquires k-space data, `S`, and then takes 3D inverse Fourier Transform to reconstruct the actual image in the spatial domain, which is in the form of `M.exp(j.P)`, in which `M` is the magnitude image and `P` is the phase image.

Now imagine what I have is being the magnitude and phase image and I want to generate `S` from them.

Now I checked my phase image and has values between 0 and 4096; So, first I have to normalize it to the `[-pi,pi]` range. Then, I can calculate `S` as the 3D Fourier Transform of the `I = M.*exp(j.*P)`.

Is there anything else that I should consider in this process?

Now, how can I calculate phase image, `P`, from the complex/raw image, `I`? I tried MATLAB's built-in function, `angle`; So, `P1 = angle(I)`, but I noticed `P1` and `P` are not equal, even `exp(j*P1)` is not equal to `exp(j*P)`. However, when I ignore the magnitude image, `I1 = exp(j*P)`, and calculate `P2` from that (`P2 = angle(I1)`), then the `exp(j*P2)` is equal to `exp(j*P)`!! I think the reason is the zero values of `M`, but I don't what is the correct way to regenerate `P` when I have `I = M.*exp(j.*P)`.

Comment: It might help if you provide your programming environment in tags and/or description. MathLab? R? Python? COBOL4MRI?

Comment: @ArturBiesiadowski what's MathLab?

Comment: I was expecting to be asked what is COBOL4MRI :) MathLab is portmanteau word for MatLab+Mathematica from person who never used any of them before. In any case, after edit, we now know it was MatLab.

Answer (score 0):

You are computing the complex image by applying M.exp(j.P).

You need a further step to get the k-space data by applying inverse Fourier Transform as follows:

Matlab code:

```
complex_img = M.*exp(j.P);
ksp= fftshift(ifft2(fftshift(complex_img)));
```